# Given a SQL Server 2008 R2 *.mdf file, how can I import it to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a small SQL Server 2008 R2 *.mdf database file. I'm running Ubuntu and don't have SQL Server 2008 installed (and would prefer not to install it into my VM, if at all possible).

How can I import this data into a MySQL instance? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And MDF file is an internal file to SQL Server. One way to import it would be to attach it to a SQL Server and then exporting the data

- SQL Integration Services
- Custom Code
- Using a conversion tool such as those listed in this article: [Migrating from Microsoft SQL Server and Access to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html)

However since you don't want to install SQL Server one suggestion perhaps using MONO to attach the mdf as datacontext in their equivalent of Linq2SQL and reading the data out your self.